# what's the word/idea that everything has to be tested by science for it to count as fact?

Tags: ethics, epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

**UPDATE** -- go educate yourself --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEPcQ6sIOTY

---

**note:** being helpful is more important than anything else, please recommend in answers, comments, etc.

---

- **[ solved ]** what's the word/idea that everything has to be tested by science for it to count as fact?
- **[ ]** also the word/idea for anything i see and experience in the material-chemical universe as real?
- **[ solved ]** also the word/idea that meaning in human-created languages changes over time? (don't make me have to cite chomsky, this is elementary and basic)

for example, if i see the earth as flat, that would count as 'real' ('fact' is also completely fine as meaning is based on context)

if science discovers the earth is not flat, that would count as the new 'fact'

- **[ ]** also **what is the most leading edge and current method physicists and computer scientists use to try to find discoveries? (within the last 5 years or so)**

---

for human language (not computational), there is absolutely no progress in human-created languages, just change

there's only progress in science

progress in aesthetics and what counts as valuable/beautiful is based on how someone feels, and would be known as a **feeling of progress**

for everything that can count as 'valuable/beautiful' (which is everything), for aspects that can currently be quantified, those will be based on data, and if felt, those would then ultimately/conclusively be based on how someone feels

- **[ ]** what's the word/idea closest to this?

this is the key distinction between

- facts and
- feelings, human-created values, all closely related human-created words

no beliefs or feelings ever needs to be 'justified', they only need to be 'felt'

the only test for what is fact is science

- **what works** in the material-chemical-digital universe

if X is **likely to work**, that's call **probability**

---

please see [Please recommend the idea/concept/word that has been imagined by the human mind that is closest to these ideas](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/42354/please-recommend-the-idea-concept-word-that-has-been-imagined-by-the-human-mind)

in full

- **[ ]** please post in answer, comment, external link, etc.

---

**key readings** --

https://www.edge.org/annual-questions

---

Comment: I am afraid this question is not much clearer than the closed one. The answer to the title question is [scientism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientism). How the text after bullet points is related to the title question is unclear. There might be an additional question there but the text is too confusing to discern what it is. And in any case it should be asked separately unless it is closely related to the title one. If so, please condense the current text (you can delete most of it) and clearly explain the connection.

Comment: thank you for the first word/idea. please see, which i now need to re-add -- "**note:** being helpful is more important than anything else, please recommend in answers, comments, etc." --- **please care to read up fully on the facts & ideas that humanity has produced thus far** to see how things can relate, have a nice day/evening/night, etc.

Comment: Monism is probably the word you're looking for in your second question

Comment: You prove the earth is a sphere using a mobile phone and two sticks by the way. Also you can percieve the earths curvature by watching ships on the horizon.

Comment: "mobile phone and two sticks" -- that's science, can be tested -- "perceive the earths curvature" -- perception is fully covered in the link, it's in the domain of neuroscience. all ideas are caused by the connection of neurons and are imagined by brains

Comment: This is incredibly straining to try and look at as a question. Have you tried writing out what your question is in paragraph form using complete sentences instead of bullet points and unpunctuated clauses? Trying to sit down and write the idea out in paragraph form might help you coalesce what it is you are trying to ask which will in turn help others understand how they can provide an answer.

Comment: would you consider representing/presenting math in large blocks of text? have you considered that yet? are you well-versed in UX and usability topics? -- perhaps more innovative things would be of interest to you -- https://vimeo.com/115154289

Comment: Seconded, write in complete sentences. Your question is too disjointed and unclear. It might be clear to you what you are asking, but not using clear unambiguous sentences that convey a complete idea means that it is unclear to the rest of us.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has stated that they already know the answer to the question and are merely trying to see "if we know anything." The sporadic and hard to read formatting of the multiple questions mean that few other people if any will find it helpful and the OP stated they already knew the answer, so this question serves no functional purpose on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"also the word/idea that meaning in human-created languages changes over time?"

Semantic Change or Drift

Scientism seems also to be the answer to your other questions.

"what's the word/idea closest to this?"

If "progress" means something like the philosophy of Optimism, then there is no progress in modern science. So in the " 'valuable/beautiful'" sense, the word would be Optimism, or Best of All Possible Worlds, i.e., the world where True progress is possible.

The "what works" standard isn't progress in the older sense for the reason that something bad for people can work. The older standard makes the improvement of human life its measure.

Comment: thank you for the language, semantics word/idea. as for 'then there is no progress in modern science', obviously that's -- not -- what my usage of progress means. everything i said is consistent, and 100% perfect. please see the additional links as they're highly valuable/beautiful for your **progress** & personal growth. please do not cite old and outdated crap when we are in 2017 given that we desire **progress**, thanks

Comment: I know what you had in mind by progress, change is a better word for that.

Comment: 100% wrong, you clearly don't, you need to progress your life, and need more personal growth in your person. a severe lack of education is bad for you

Comment: In philosophy history is necessary because if one doesn't see where the current ideas came from one can't regard them critically. One gets the sense that the latest notions have somehow fallen from the sky, been discovered or invented yesterday out of nothing, and that they are unquestionably true. Emanuel Kant, as you may know, was working with, amoungst other arguments, the distinction suggested by Hume. Is/ought. The ought starts to include also beauty and taste/feeling in Kant. The arguments are not self evident, & their authority or power is at work in the latest and greatest.

Comment: 1) "can't regard" -- no, because meanings change. ideas also change. you dont seem to understand the distinction between the two. 2) "from the sky" -- they're ALWAYS been from the sky. you don't understand that all philo and all ideas are imagined. 3) you need to read up on the basic links above. 4) there would be zero -- zero **progress** talking to someone with the ideas that you have

Comment: I know Wolfram's work. He studied the history of maths very deeply. That's how he was able to come to his views. You also have a link to an article about the history of the concept of science...  I've given you very good info and what praise do I get? Enough of your insane abuse!

Comment: the only part that mattered was my first comment. i already asked more than once to not cite outdated crap. you continue with your nonsensical, foolish, non-tested, non-scientific ideas of 'deserving praise' somehow? and 'insane abuse' somehow? hahaha, what a joke. filled with **imaginary assumptions & ideas**. you saw some links, i don't care, it's not for my benefit, it's for yours. because all **ideas are imagined** is elementary and basic. **zero progress**